# The string did not match the expected pattern in evaluateJavaScript

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I've loaded a page and am looking for all the `<script>` with `type=text/javascript`, but no matter what I do I get an exception

```swift
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelectorAll('script[type=text\\/javascript]').length;)
```

> The string did not match the expected pattern.

```swift
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelectorAll('script[type=text/javascript]').length;)
```

> The string did not match the expected pattern.

```swift
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelectorAll('script').length;)
```

> 19

Got no clue how to add a type filter in there, it works in the Console in Safari

Comment: You missed quotes around `text/javascript`.
This works for me on FIrefox `document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/javascript"]')`

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelectorAll('script[type=\"text/javascript\"]').length;") { result, err in
        print(result ?? "")
        print(err ?? "")
    }

}
```

@VedantBang's comment matters